# Return the number of foreign keys in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I have a table `news_archive` and `topics`. For `topics`, I have a `rowid` column that acts as the PK, and a FK that references the column `filed` in `news_archive`.

So for `news_archive`:

```
row_id | filed
   1   |   3
   2   |   3
   3   |   1
   4   |   2
```

and for `topics`:

```
rowid | title
  1   | foo
  2   | bar
  3   | foobar
```

I would like to have a select MySQL query where I can get the `title` value and the number of the `rowid` of the `rowid`. So I would like something along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT title, (number of times rowid was referenced) FROM topics WHERE rowid = 3;
```

Thanks.

Comment: According to your examples what is your expected result?

Comment: Join the other table, and count the rows.

Comment: As other users said, join the tables and count the rows grouping by title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select title, (select count(*) tot from news_archive na WHERE na.filled = tc.rowid) total from topics tc WHERE rowid = 3;
```

Inner Join Solution:

```
SELECT title, count(na.filed) as total from topics tc INNER JOIN news_archive na 
on na.filed = tc.rowid
group by filed, title
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nzvUH87rLEdreem2YAxowj/1

Comment: Isn't this slower/less efficient than `inner join`?

Comment: It depends on how much data you have. If you have more data then join is better solution.

Comment: I have ~10k rows, can you provide an inner join solution?

Comment: Pls check updated inner join solution